"Duration" and "BadNodeID" errors when using ros_opcua_impl_python_opcua package?
I am trying to create an OPC-UA server in ROS-noetic for my robot so a client can subscribe to its topics. When I use "roslaunch ros_opcua_impl_python_opcua rosopcua.launch" command I have the error below. I appreciate any help or guidance.

[ERROR] [1715868776.735945, 15.838000]: Can't create type with name
Duration [INFO] [1715868776.745651, 15.842000]: Created ROS Action
with name: /xy_controller/follow_joint_trajectory [INFO]
[1715868776.763320, 15.866000]: Created ROS Topic with name:
/z_controller/state [INFO] [1715868776.768779, 15.870000]: Creating
Action with name: /z_controller/follow_joint_trajectory Traceback
(most recent call last):   File
"/home/hp/gantry_ws/src/ros_opcua_communication/ros_opcua_impl_python_opcua/scripts/ros_server.py",
line 103, in 
main(sys.argv)   File "/home/hp/gantry_ws/src/ros_opcua_communication/ros_opcua_impl_python_opcua/scripts/ros_server.py",
line 99, in main
rosserver = ROSServer()   File "/home/hp/gantry_ws/src/ros_opcua_communication/ros_opcua_impl_python_opcua/scripts/ros_server.py",
line 63, in init
ros_topics.refresh_topics_and_actions(self.namespace_ros, self, self.topicsDict, self.actionsDict,   File
"/home/hp/gantry_ws/src/ros_opcua_communication/ros_opcua_impl_python_opcua/scripts/ros_topics.py",
line 282, in refresh_topics_and_actions
actionsdict[correct_name] = ros_actions.OpcUaROSAction(server,   File
"/home/hp/gantry_ws/src/ros_opcua_communication/ros_opcua_impl_python_opcua/scripts/ros_actions.py",
line 62, in init
self.main_node = self.parent.add_object(   File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opcua/common/node.py",
line 661, in add_object
return opcua.common.manage_nodes.create_object(self, nodeid, bname, objecttype)   File
"/home/hp/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opcua/common/manage_nodes.py",
line 58, in create_object
return node.Node(parent.server, _create_object(parent.server, parent.nodeid, nodeid, qname, ua.ObjectIds.BaseObjectType))   File
"/home/hp/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opcua/common/manage_nodes.py",
line 171, in _create_object
results[0].StatusCode.check()   File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opcua/ua/uatypes.py",
line 218, in check
raise UaStatusCodeError(self.value) opcua.ua.uaerrors._auto.BadNodeIdExists: "The requested node id is
already used by another node."(BadNodeIdExists)

